# Is $f(x,y)=x^{xy}$ continuous for positive $x$ and real $y$?

Tags: continuity, multivalued-functions

Can someone please explain to me why this function is continuous?
$$f(x,y)=x^{xy},\quad  x>0, \quad y\in \mathbb{R} $$
I have thought like this that we can rewrite the question in this form: $f(x,y) = e^{xy\ln x}$ and $e^x$ is continuous and $\ln$ also continuous but I don't know how should I prove that x and y are continuous too?

I know the definition of continuity at a point "$a$" that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $$ 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x,y)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$

Comment: You could say that $g(x,y) = x$ and $g(x,y) = y$ are continuous because they are polynomials

Comment: @Nima As a starting point, please edit your query to include the (single variable) definition of a continuous function [e.g. what does it mean in terms of epsilon and delta for a function g(x) to be continuous].  Then, edit your query again to expand the definition of a continuous function in two variables [i.e. what does it mean for f(x,y) to be continuous].  Then show work in your query trying to prove that the given f(x,y) satisfies the requirements for a 2 variable continuous function.

Comment: @Nima Your definition of the requirement for a 2-variable function to be continuous at a given point is wrong.  For 1 variable, the definition is : $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ denotes that for each $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists a $\delta > 0$, such that $0 < |x - a| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon.$ ...see next comment.

Comment: $y$ is continuous, $x\log x$ is continuous, $xy\log(x)$ is continuous and $\exp(xy\log x)=x^{xy}$ is continuous in the given region.

Comment: @Nima For a 2 variable function, the domain is $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(x,y) = (a,b)$ denotes that for each $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists a $\delta > 0,$ such that $0 < |(x,y) - (a,b)| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x,y) - f(a,b)| < \epsilon.$  Further, $f(x,y)$ is a continuous function denotes that it is continuous **everywhere** which means that for any $(a,b), f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(a,b).$

Comment: @Nima The comments of Omnomnomnom or Jack D'Aurizio may well provide you with an easier way of proving the result than my (very basic) approach.  That depends on the context of the problem, i.e. what previous theorems have been established in your math book or math class that you are allowed to assume are true.  If you can't build off of their comments, then you can use my approach, and prove that for any $(a,b)$ and any $\epsilon$ you can find a satisfying $\delta.$

Comment: Note the alteration of the domain: the first variable must be positive.  Therefore, you are allowed to assume that $a>0.$

Comment: @user2661923  my text book doesn't show any detail about how we should proceed with this type of question just mention little about epsilon and delta but doesn't show how should we solve these type of question, i don't really know for sure that this is the best way that solve this problem as i did

Comment: @Nima My response will be too long winded for a comment, so I will post an *answer* that is really a **guide.**

Answer (score 1):

Again, let me emphasize that I am giving you a very basic approach.  The comments of others, if usable, give an easier solution.

Basic approach : 
(1) Compute $|(x,y) - (a,b)|$ in terms of $x,y,a,b$. 
(2) Compute $|f(x,y) - f(a,b)|$ in terms of $x,y,a,b$. 
(3) Requiring that $|(x,y) - (a,b)| < \delta,$ form an inequality in $x,y,a,b$ and $\delta.$ 
(4) Requiring that $|f(x,y) - f(a,b)| < \epsilon,$ form an inequality in $x,y,a,b$ and $\epsilon.$ 
(5) Given any $\epsilon$ and given any $(a,b)$ in the domain of $f$, demonstrate that you can construct a $\delta$ such that whenever requirement (3) above is satisfied, requirement (4) will also be satisfied.

Note that with $(a,b)$ in the domain of $f$ requirements (3) and (4) above only pertain to any $(x,y)$ that satisfy the particular requirement and are **also** in the domain of $f$.